# What are the statistics about follow-ons not enforced in tests?

Tags: cricket, statistics

In tests, a team can enforce [follow-on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Follow-on) if they must have a minimum lead of 200 runs after the second innings. However, often the leading team will decide not to enforce follow-on and go on to bat in the third innings, with weather forecasts, condition of the pitch, number of overs bowled in the second innings and bowlers' and fielders' fitness being important factors swaying the decision.

What is the percentage of matches where the leading team chose not to enforce follow-on? I am focused on international cricket, but domestic records can also be included.

Comment: Title could be a bit less vague, you're only seeking a specific statistic, not all of them. I was trigger-ready to flag *too broad/unclear*, but the body saves it.

Comment: @Nij: Perhaps you're right. Feel free to edit it how you see fit. I can't think of a way to update it effectively.

Answer (score 2):

From [blog of **espncricinfo**](http://www.espncricinfo.com/blogs/content/story/797859.html) by author *KARTIKEYA DATE*.

Which summarizes as:
[image: when enforcing follow on]

[image: when enforcing follow on]

As these picture explain there is not much difference between enforcing a follow-on and not enforcing one. And enforcement rate has been clearly dropped, and success on not enforcing has improved.

[image: Test span table]

*Enforcement rate is the percentage of Tests in which the follow-on was available and was actually enforced.